# running aws batch jobs manually

Tags: docker, cron, pytest, amazon-ecr, aws-batch

I am developing automated tests for one of our GUI based app using Pytest framework. I've created a docker image with series of tests for a particular GUI functionality and it is stored in AWS ECR as an image.I've also setup an AWS Batch computing env with a cron schedule to trigger the tests (image) at a particlar time/day which is working fine.

I've couple of questions regarding this:
Is there a way to trigger the tests from AWS without using the cron schedule? This is to enable business users with necessary AWS rights so that they can run the tests independently without waiting for the cron to run the tests.

Secondly, what is the best way to run automation tests for more than one GUI functionalities (pages)? There are about 15 different types of pages within the app that needs to be automated for testing. One way is to create 15 different images to test them and store them in ECR. But it sounds little inefficient way of doing things. Is there a better alternative like creating just one image for these 15 different pages. If so, how can I selectively run tests for a particular GUI page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is no, you can't manually trigger a CRON scheduled batch job. If you wanted user's to run the tests you would need to switch to event driven jobs and have the user's create events that trigger the job - drop a file into S3, send a message to an SQS queue etc. You could also wrap your batch job in a State Machine, which is then trivial to manually execute

Answer (score 0):

> I've couple of questions regarding this: Is there a way to trigger the
> tests from AWS without using the cron schedule? This is to enable
> business users with necessary AWS rights so that they can run the
> tests independently without waiting for the cron to run the tests.

I think you are asking if a user can run this AWS Batch Job Definition manually in addition to the cron scheduled process?

If so the answer is yes, either with access to the Batch management console or using the CLI (or if you have some other GUI application with the SDK). They would need an IAM user with a role permissions for Batch, ECS, and other AWS resources.

> Secondly, what is the best way to run automation tests for more than one GUI functionalities (pages)? There are about 15 different types of pages within the app that needs to be automated for testing. One way is to create 15 different images to test them and store them in ECR. But it sounds little inefficient way of doing things. Is there a better alternative like creating just one image for these 15 different pages. If so, how can I selectively run tests for a particular GUI page.

I would look into continuous integration testing methods. This is the problem those systems are designed to solve.

Comment: Ok, can you pls elaborate how I can achieve this with continuous integration? Currently I have one repo and one Docker file for the image. Do I create different images with different Docker files (using sub-directories within my repo) and publish them all in ECR? That still doesn't solve the issue, sorry unless I am missing something here. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I do not have enough information from above to be able to give you solid advice on testing your application. Testing is a big challenge and there are multiple ways to do it. One approach is to leverage a continuous integration system like Jenkins to write your tests and trigger the tests when you make commits to your repository. These systems build applications and/or containers on the fly to test.

Comment: In other words, a CI system will free you from having to manually build the container to test. A continuous delivery system (the CD from CI/CD) will push a passing build to a release target, which can be an ECR repository, and downloadable binary, etc.